# Best way to check if an object is None?

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

How should I fix this error? Seems like an unresolved issue in this repository: https://github.com/shayanzare007/EntitySentiment/issues/7

```
$ python RunRNN.py 
Number of unique words: 9869
Opening the file...
File successfully read
Opening the file...
File successfully read
Opening the file...
File successfully read
Number of training samples 5003
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RunRNN.py", line 84, in <module>
    curve = model.train_sgd(X,Y,idxiter_random,None,400,400) 
  File "/scratch2/debate_tweets/sentiment/EntitySentiment/nn/base.py", line 386, in train_sgd
    if idxiter == None: # default training schedule
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I'd instead do `if idxiter is None`.

Comment: Right, since None is really a value and not a reference, it is a lot safer to use it because comparison can have unexpected behavior when the object you compare to None can have a type which doesn't support the comparison well

Comment: http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.fi/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html

Comment: @LouisSugy it's not only safer, it's also faster. Nice when those line up.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks a lot. Can you please write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing an object for nullity, the recommended practice is to *always* use `is`:

```
if idxiter is None:
    ...
```

It's safer, especially because not all objects support equality comparisons with `None`.